# Is there an issue where Deadpool kills off everyone?

Tags: marvel, comics, episode-identification, deadpool

I saw this post on Facebook:

[image]

> Deadpool once killed off the entire Marvel Universe, including the writers themselves. #8fact

And I thought that if it was real, it would be a good issue.

So, is there any issue where Deadpool kills off everyone, as well as the writers?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is the primary plot of "[**Deadpool Kills the Marvel Universe**](http://marvel.wikia.com/Deadpool_Killogy)", a four-comic what-if 'killogy' event from 2011-2012. The official [Marvel.com](http://marvel.com/comics/issue/41553/deadpool_kills_the_marvel_universe_2011_1) site has this to say;

> "What if everthing you thought was funny about Deadpool…was actually
>   just disturbing? • **What if he decided to kill everyone and
>   everything that makes up the Marvel Universe?** • What if he actually
>   pulled it off? Would that be FUN for you? • The Merc with a Mouth
>   takes a turn for the twisted in a weekly horror comic like no other…"

At the very end, he literally breaks (well, cuts) the 4th wall, the suggestion being that he's going to kill the writers.

[image]
[image]

---

This is also the plot of [Deadpool Kills The Marvel Universe **Again**](https://comicstore.marvel.com/Deadpool-Kills-The-Marvel-Universe-Again-2017-1-of-5/digital-comic/45217)

> Remember the time Deadpool went a little TOO crazy and killed the
>   entire Marvel Universe? Well, this isn't that. This is a DIFFERENT
>   time. Writer Cullen Bunn and artist Dalibor Talajic (A.K.A. the
>   creators behind DEADPOOL KILLS THE MARVEL UNIVERSE) have reunited for
>   ANOTHER tale of Deadpool taking out all of your faves in the most
>   horrific ways possible! It's gonna hurt him more than it hurts you…and
>   you're gonna love it!

This time it doesn't end with the writers being killed though.

Comment: Deadpool's offing of Wolverine is wonderfully simple in that one.

Comment: @joshbirk How did he do it?

Comment: @Trenin IIRC, he waits for Wolverine to get drunk and ambushes him in an alley.  He then shoves his head into a circuit breaker box and electrocutes him via all the wonderful metal in his body.  Instant brain death.  It's brilliant, imho, because a) he doesn't try to fight him and b) it's a realistic way around Wolverine's healing factor almost despite how ludicrously powerful some writers treat it.

Comment: @joshbirk - Except that we've seen a bunch of times that electricity doesn't kill Wolverine

Comment: @Richard we've seen a lot of BS when it comes to what does and does not kill Wolverine.

Comment: I have this strange impression I learned about this story on another question but can't remember which one. I think it even had a panel of Deadpool saying he killed Spider-Man, Marvel's favorite. I think I'm spending too much time reading random questions on this site.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DIrIvKKT_nk Strong 'bus that couldn't slow down' vibes from this one

Answer (score 11):

This is referring to the four-issue limited series [Deadpool Kills The Marvel Universe](http://marvel.wikia.com/Deadpool_Kills_the_Marvel_Universe_Vol_1_1).

[Wikipedia explains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadpool#Deadpool_Kills_the_Marvel_Universe):

> In the storyline Deadpool Kills the Marvel Universe, the X-Men send Deadpool to a mental hospital for therapy. The doctor treating him is actually Psycho-Man in disguise, who attempts to torture and brainwash Deadpool into becoming his personal minion. The procedure fails, but leaves Deadpool even more mentally unhinged; **as a result, he kills Psycho-Man and begins assassinating every superhero and supervillain on Earth one by one in an attempt (apparently) to rebel against his comic book creators. The book ends with him breaking into the 'real' world and confronting the Marvel writers and artists who are currently writing the book. Before he proceeds to enter he turns to the reader, promising that once he's done with this universe, "I'll find you soon enough."**